# DOM manipulation inside loop happens too fast

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, delay

Trying to flash divs in a different color with some time between them (not using jquery). the program works perfectly in the debugger, but when running it all the changes happen too fast and the user can't see a thing.

tried using setTimeout to no avail (probably not using it right)

```
function makeBoard() {
var squareNum = 4
var selected
container = document.createElement('div')
container.id = 'container'
document.body.appendChild(container);
for (let index = 0; index < squareNum; index++) {
    squareDiv = document.createElement('div')
    squareDiv.className = 'square'
    squareDiv.id = '' + (index + 1)
    container.appendChild(squareDiv)
}
selected = document.getElementById('1')
selected.classList.add('selected')
return selected
}

function dimSwitch() {
var turnCnt = 1
var posIndex = 0
var selectedDivs = []
var tempCnt = 0
var tempIndex = 0
var timeNum = getMaxPos()
while (tempCnt < timeNum) {
    var posIndex = posArr.indexOf(turnCnt, tempIndex)
    tempIndex = posIndex + 1
    while (posIndex !== -1) {
        selectedDivs.push(document.getElementById(posIndex + 1 + ''))
        posIndex = posArr.indexOf(turnCnt, tempIndex)
        tempIndex = posIndex + 1
    } 
    selectDiv(selectedDivs) //After this i would like a small delay
    turnCnt++
    tempCnt++
    for (let index = 0; index < selectedDivs.length; index++) {
        selectedDivs[index].classList.remove('selected')
    }
    selectedDivs = []
}
}

function drawMove(currDiv, direction) {
 var nextDiv
 currDiv.classList.remove('selected')
 nextDiv = document.getElementById((parseInt(currDiv.id) + direction))
 nextDiv.classList.add('selected')
 return nextDiv
}

function selectDiv(divs) {
for (let index = 0; index < divs.length; index++) {
    divs[index].classList.add('selected')
}
}
function getMaxPos() {
var maxNum = 0
for (let index = 0; index < posArr.length; index++) {
    if (posArr[index] > maxNum) maxNum = posArr[index]
}
return maxNum
}

var TurnNum = 4 //Number of turns
var posArr = [1]
var turnCnt = 1
var currDiv = makeBoard()

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        //Left Key -1
        posArr[turnCnt] = posArr[turnCnt - 1] - 1
        currDiv = drawMove(currDiv, -1)
        turnCnt++
        break;

    case 39:
        //Right key +1
        posArr[turnCnt] = posArr[turnCnt - 1] + 1
        currDiv = drawMove(currDiv, 1)
        turnCnt++
        break;

    case 40:
        currDiv.classList.remove('selected')
        dimSwitch()
        break;
}
if (turnCnt === TurnNum) {
    currDiv.classList.remove('selected')
    dimSwitch()
}
};
```

the function selectDivs should run with some time between each execution
whenever using a delay or timeout it freezes or dosent work correctly
The user should be able to see which divs are in red ('selected' class) before i remove the class in the for loop.

[JS FIDDLE FULL CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/rd2n068c/)

This is how I tried using setTimeout but the rest of the code keeps running in the background and what i see is all the divs in red:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
for (let index = 0; index < selectedDivs.length; index++) { 
       selectedDivs[index].classList.remove('selected') 
   } 
 },1000)
```

Comment: Obviously this code will run immidiately. How did you use setTimeout and didn't work?

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
            for (let index = 0; index < selectedDivs.length; index++) {
                selectedDivs[index].classList.remove('selected')
            }
        },1000)

the rest of the code keeps running in the background and what i see is all the divs in red

Comment: Please post a minimal **working** example (or in this case **not working**), including HTML (and anything that is important), so people don't have a hard time reconstructing your case. That way it's much easier and faster to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the loop code inside a setTimeout block so entire the loop will run at a glance but after 1000 miliseconds. If you want the elements appear one by one by 1 second delays, you can change the logic to this so set a different timeout `(1000 * index)` for each element:

```
for (let index = 0; index < selectedDivs.length; index++) { 
   setTimeout(function(){ 
        selectedDivs[index].classList.remove('selected') 
    }
    , (1000 * index)
    )
}
```

Comment: this loop should run at a glance. 
i would like the delay to happen after i run the selectDivs function
so the user can see which divs are in red

Comment: i implemented this logic on the second while loop (the loop that gets the divs to be changed and changes them) and on the for loop you showed and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to do a recursive loop, using the timeout to delay the call to itself. Proof of concept below:

```js
var childDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.child'); 

function selectDivs(divs, index, delay) {
  divs[index].classList.add('selected');
  
  delay = delay || 1000;  // if you want to change the delay
  index++
  
  if (index < divs.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      selectDivs(divs, index, delay);    
    }, delay);    
  }
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body onload="selectDivs(childDivs, 0)">

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

I would personally use CSS as far as I can, setting a CSS-variable to delay the change. Only for the purpose of being able to follow what happens easier in the DOM.

```js
var childDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.child'); 

function selectDivs(children) {
  let child = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    child = children[i];
    
    child.style.setProperty('--background-animation-delay', i+'s');
    child.classList.add('selected');  
  }
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  --background-animation-delay: 0s;
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  background-color: #ffff00;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
  transition: background-color 0s var(--background-animation-delay);
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="selectDivs(childDivs)">

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```